# database updating using php

Tags: php, mysql

well i just made a form in HTML witch accepts user inputs and a mysql database to store them, now in the php file everything goes well no errors but the problem is the data never displays in the database, here is the php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submitacc"])){

    $servernm = "localhost";
    $serverusrnm = "root";
    $serverpass = "2003";
    $db = "blue";

    $conn = new mysqli($servernm, $serverusrnm, $serverpass, $db);

    if($conn ->connect_error){
        die("connection failed".$conn->connect_error);
    }

    $fnm = $_POST["fnm"];
    $lnm = $_POST["lnm"];
    $mail = $_POST["mail"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $gender = $_POST["gender"];
    if(isset($_POST["gender"])&&$_POST["gender"]=="male"){
        $gender = "male";
    }else {
        $gender = "female";
    }


$mysql="update createacc set fnm = '$fnm', lnm = '$lnm', mail = '$mail', passwod = '$pass', age = '$age', gender = '$gender' ";

if($conn->query($mysql)== true){
    echo "record updated";
}else {
    echo "error updating record".$conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: well you have an `update` statement ... that's not an `insert`

Comment: For the sake of all that's holy, don't post your DB credentials

Comment: And besides, you didn't execute the query.

Comment: @Antono Then what is `if($conn->query($mysql)== true){`?

Comment: I don't see a WHERE clause in your $mysql variable. Are you trying to update an existing record or create a new one?

Comment: Do you really have a column named `passwod`? That looks like a typo for `password`.

Comment: You should also learn to use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_query() instead of query(). Also use WHERE clause in your $mysql variable. The WHERE clause specifies which record or records that should be updated. If you omit the WHERE clause, all records will be updated!

Example:

```
if(mysqli_query($conn , $mysql)){

    echo "Records were updated successfully.";

} else {

    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $mysql. " . mysqli_error($conn);

}
```

Comment: `$conn->query($mysql)` is the same as `mysqli_query($conn, $mysql)`.

Comment: It's generally considered wrong to mix OO and functional use of mysqli. It will work, but it's poor style.